# How to get index or location of point selected in edit mode using python API?

Tags: python, vertices

If I have selected a vertex in edit mode, how can I get its index in the on the list of vertices or its vertex location using python?
For example, this is my selection.

[image]

WHat I am looking for is to print to console the index of that vertex (107) or its location ([0.19,1.23, -0.5]).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way to get selected vertices via python (without iterating over the entire mesh)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1412/efficient-way-to-get-selected-vertices-via-python-without-iterating-over-the-en)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1412/86891) and its numerous answers as a base for an efficient code, you can use this script :

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

mode = bpy.context.active_object.mode
# Keep track of previous mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
# Go into object mode to update the selected vertices

obj = bpy.context.object
# Get the currently select object
sel = np.zeros(len(obj.data.vertices), dtype=np.bool)
# Create a numpy array with empty values for each vertex

obj.data.vertices.foreach_get('select', sel)
# Populate the array with True/False if the vertex is selected

for ind in np.where(sel==True)[0]:
    # Loop over each currently selected vertex
    v = obj.data.vertices[ind]
    print('Vertex {} at position {} is selected'.format(v.index, v.co))
    # If you just want the first one you can break directly here
    # break

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=mode)
# Go back to the previous mode
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gorgious. That is exactly what I was looking for. I managed to get to show the index with bm.verts.select but every time I run it, was showing the same index. Yours works perfectly.