# Align pentagons to cover UV canvas

Tags: python, materials, uv

After I subdivided the iconsphere twice, I would like to select all pentagons shown in the image here, and unwrap them to fill the whole uv editor window, i.e. all pentagons overlap eache other.

How to accomplish this, for the benefit of texture assigining?

Thank you!

[image: in the uv editing mode]

Comment: This post is tagged 'Python'... do you want to script this?

Comment: Yes, actually I find it straightforward to use codings... And how to generalize this problem, say expand islands of various shapes to the four corners? Thank you!

Comment: If you're looking exclusively for a script.. maybe you should edit to make that explicit?  ..  the more general mapping of polygons to quads, sure, is another question.

Comment: @RobinBetts Thank you, I'll reconsider :-) and some handy UV tool may also prove useful! :-D

Answer (score 4):

Because all pentagons have the same rotation (-18°), aligning is simple.

1. Select one face on a pentagon
2. Go *Select > Select Linked*, (<kbd>Shift + L</kbd>) to select remaining faces
3. Set UV position to 0,5 (or any other coordinate)

[image: List item]

---

And for expanding across the whole UV canvas.

1. Rotate the resulting pentagon 18°
2. Check *UV > Constrain to image bounds*
3. Scale up the pentagon, it will stop automatically at borders

[image]

Comment: Hi, there.. the shipped add-on [Magic UV](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/uv/magic_uv.html#copy-paste-uv) has a Copy/Paste UV between islands op, which could speed this up a bit? ..  I don't know whether the `Python' tag on OP is significant ..

Comment: Thanks, good to know, that speeds it up a lot :).

Comment: Ahh! OK, [nice find](https://imgur.com/a/3REpLJx)!  :)

Comment: Actually I got some inspiration from the post with the following url,  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173627/how-to-get-index-or-location-of-point-selected-in-edit-mode-using-python-api. Combine it with the instruction "bpy.ops.uv.select_linked_pick(extend=True, deselect=False)", and we can get an automated script.