# Invert vertex selection with Python

Tags: python, vertices, selection-tools

I have a few vertices selected, obviously in edit mode.

[image: selection]

Running `bpy.ops.info.select_all(action='INVERT')`  in the Python console gives me a `RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.info.select_all.poll() failed, context is incorrect` though ?

That's exactly the command the GUI shows me when hovering `Select > Invert`, and doing it though the GUI works of course.

Comment: Consider using low-level functions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1417/31447 Otherwise have a look into: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add

Comment: Thanks, doing it low-level would have been my next try, but fortunately I found the right command. This whole context thing is total nonsense from the point of software engineering. If I want to run a command, then do whatever it takes to run it and set some context or whatever. Thanks for your suggestions !

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: The labeling in Blender is apparently wrong. The right command is `bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='INVERT')`