# Is there a faster way to control the shapekey in Python?

Tags: python, scripting

I'm controlling Blender's shapekey in the following Python script.

This still works fast enough, but is there any low layer code that works faster?

```
import bpy
selectList = bpy.context.selected_objects

if selectList[0].data.shape_keys:
    for block in selectList[0].data.shape_keys.key_blocks:
        block.value = 0.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**foreach_set**

To avoid looping over collection and setting a property value per item  can instead use `collection.foreach_set(property_name, values)` [Find numerous links re this']

The `values` list is a flat list, *eg* if the property `uv` for example is a vector then the list

```
values = [u0, v0, u1, v1, ...., un, vn]
```

For keyblock values

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

ob = context.object
me = ob.data
sks = me.shape_keys

if sks:
    vals = (0.5, ) * len(sks.key_blocks)
    sks.key_blocks.foreach_set("value", vals)
```

Comment: Great! Is there a way to avoid the assignment if, for example, I don't want to assign a value to the third value of key_blocks? Is there any way to have a list of [smile_L,eyeClose_L,smile_R,,eyeClose_R] and ignore smile_R?

Comment: Can load the current values into a flat list  with `foreach_get`  _eg_ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1412/efficient-way-to-get-selected-vertices-via-python-without-iterating-over-the-en/233823#233823