# Is there a way to select all cameras without iterating through every object in a scene?

Tags: python, camera

I require a way to select certain cameras in a scene. My plan is to get all camera objects in a scene, and then based on their names get the ones that I need.

Currently I’m selecting all cameras like this:

```
all_cams = [ob for ob in list(bpy.context.scene.objects) if ob.type == ‘CAMERA’]
```

But i think there should be a better way to do this, without iterating through all objects in a scene.
There is the  `D.cameras` collection and from there I can get all data-block names. But how I can go from data-block names to the object name?

Or at least how do I select the cameras using their data-block name? ( then I can work further based on selected objects)

Do you have any ideas how I can achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: Have you identified this operation as a bottleneck in terms of speed ? It should be pretty fast unless you have thousands upon thousands of objects. Otherwise you can use a custom collection property to store camera objects in the scene for instance. Using data block names will be even less efficient because of the lookup : `[ob for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects if ob.data.name in camera_names]` and even then if 2 cameras use the same data it will fail. Object data don't hold a reference to their object because they can be shared amongst an indefinite number of objects

Comment: "Have you identified this operation as a bottleneck in terms of speed ?"

Yeah, i was thinking that. Didnt have opportunity to run a test tho. I was just wondering if there is a way to do this. I'll stick to what I have right now, and if it will be a problem I will try to adress it then I guess ;p

Comment: Could perhaps  get a squeak more with a different test than equality `ob.type.startswith('CAM')` or via an attribute test  `hasattr(...)` , doubt its worth it.  Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/233823/15543

Comment: Yes there is such a way: `[camera for camera in bpy.data.cameras if bpy.context.scene.objects.get(camera.name)]`.  No guarantee that it will be faster in any given situation though.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry too much, testing all objects in the scene is lightning fast... and the winner is:

```
[ob for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects if ob.type == 'CAMERA']
```

Time measurements of a scene with `1000` cameras and `1000` default cubes.

- Code in question

  ```
  cams = [ob for ob in list(bpy.context.scene.objects) if ob.type == 'CAMERA']
  # Time: 0.0026161670684814453
  ```
- Regular list comprehension

  ```
  cams = [ob for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects if ob.type == 'CAMERA']
  # Time: 0.0021109580993652344
  ```
- Generator

  ```
  cams = (ob for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects if ob.type == 'CAMERA')
  # Time: 6.222724914550781e-05
  ```
- Prefix list comprehension

  ```
  cams = [ob for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects if ob.type.startswith('CAM')]
  # Time: 0.0025479793548583984
  ```
- Attribute list comprehension

  ```
  cams = [ob for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects if hasattr(ob.data, "lens")]
  # Time: 0.002920866012573242
  ```

Comment: The test to me illustrates that they are all almost equal apart from the generator operation which is ~30 times faster. Note that the main issue with generators is that you can only iterate over them once and then they're done.